# Как отправить логи на удалённый сервер в SourceMod?

Tags: разработка-игр, steam

Пишу плагин для CSGO и встал вопрос - как отправлять логи плагина на удалённый сервер?
Есть команда `logaddress_add_http`, но она отправляет все логи, а мне нужно отправлять логи именно плагина